# Drawing Polyline results in pixelated line

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am trying to create my own Native win32 C++ Checkbox that can have a transparent background. The idea is to make the window/widget look exactly like the Windows XP style checkbox except that it can have a transparent background.

**My Problem:** When I draw the tick for my textbox, the 'tick' line looks pixelated and jagged - see my picture below for how it looks. It does not look smooth like the actual checkbox tick.

The left checkbox is mine, the right is the default windows one I am trying to replicate:
[image]

**How can I make my tick smooth and not pixelated.** What is a Win32 GDI function I could use to draw the tick. Should I use a bitmap image instead of drawing the tick in GDI? Currently I use PolylineTo() to draw the tick. Maybe I should use PolylineToEx()?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Code for drawing the tick(this code is in WM_PAINT):

```
 HGDIOBJ hPen      = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(45,45,45)); //ExtCreatePen(PS_COSMETIC, dwPenStyle[i], 1, &lb, 0, NULL); 
 HGDIOBJ hPenOld   = SelectObject(hdc, hPen); 
 POINT tickPnts[3] = {{3,((height-CHECK_RECTH)/2)+6}, {5,((height-CHECK_RECTH)/2)+9}, {9,((height-CHECK_RECTH)/2)+2}};
 MoveToEx(hdc, tickPnts[0].x, tickPnts[0].y, NULL);
 PolylineTo(hdc, tickPnts, 3);
 SelectObject(hdc, hPenOld); 
 DeleteObject(hPen);
```

Comment: My GDI+ is very rusty, but I suspect you might want to look up texture brush usage, and use a small circular texture with alpha blended edges. You can create a pen from a brush and then draw the polyline as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses the [Marlett](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/16/10256947.aspx) font to render checkbox ticks, the window frame buttons and other scalable UI elements.  You can render the font with anti-aliasing to get smooth edges.

(This certainly used to be true anyway; I don't know for sure that the new window frame buttons in Windows 7 use the font, but the font still exists.)

GDI doesn't do any anti-aliasing, which is why your lines look jagged.

Comment: thanks for the info. Is there a WinAPI C++ way I can draw the tick using the Marlett font?

Comment: Use CreateFont to create a font handle, select it into the device context and use TextOut to write the text.  Lowercase 'a' and 'b' are ticks in Marlett.

Answer (score -1):

The standard checkbox can be transparent. See this page for an example:

http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/transparent-background-color-checkbox-help-27571202.html

In Winforms you just set the background color as `Transparent`.