# Drawing Marlett Tick: Not tall and skinny enough

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am attempting to draw a tick that looks exactly like the Windows XP CheckBox tick. I know that the Windows XP Checkbox tick is drawn using the Marlett font and I am doing the same.

My Problem is that my Marlett tick looks very squat whilst the actual tick is taller and thinner. How can I make my tick taller and thinner?

Notice how my tick on the left is too squat compared to the actual one:
[image]

What `CreateFont()` parameters do I need to change to acheive the same tick that Windows XP draws?

```
void draw(HDC hdc, PAINTSTRUCT ps)
{
    // Draws a marlett tick that is too squat, should I 
    // change the 1st param(height one) or something else?

    HFONT marlettFont = CreateFont(0, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
                         CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, TEXT("Marlett"));

    SelectObject(hdc,marlettFont);
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,0));
    DrawTextEx(hdc, TEXT("a"), -1, &tickRect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_NOCLIP, NULL);  
}
```

Comment: You do realize this is a futile attempt as this might change between any versions of windows and if the checkbox is skinned or not and depending on the DPI settings of the user?

Comment: @RedX its being used for my own NSIS installer, so it doesn't really matter

Comment: What i meant was, why don't u use the real checkbox.

Comment: @RedX you cant have a Checkbox with a transparent background, you have to make your own

Comment: Marlett is not used for check boxes in Windows XP. Windows XP uses `DrawThemeBackground`.

Comment: @RaymondChen ...the Raymond Chen :D...omg...if only I knew how to do a bowing emoticon. Thanks for the advice I'll lookup DrawThemeBackground. Thanks :D

Comment: @JakeM [Sorry!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011684/drawing-polyline-results-in-pixelated-line/11015198#11015198)